# What happens to hotkeys when doing a clean stock windows 7 install?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, hotkeys

I have a Samsung laptop and I want to do a clean stock Windows 7 install. I have a Windows 7 CD to install from.

My laptop has some special hotkeys (fn + < f key >) that interact with the volume, screen brightness, keyboard brightness, CD eject, etc. Of course, when I do a clean install, I want to still key these hotkeys.

I know this sounds like a dumb question, but before I do the clean install, I want to make sure I won't lose these hotkeys? I just wanted to make sure I did lose anything before I change something permanent.

Answer (score 3):

A lot of these things may just work out of the box, but if you go to the manufacturer's website you can generally find a downloads page that will not only have drivers for things but also any utilities, etc, that are required to use your machine's particular capabilities.